# Agregar productos automaticamente por medio de input con escaner de codigo de barras

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

tengo un problema, lo que necesito es lo siguiente, tengo un input en donde quisiera que a la hora de colocar el codigo del producto correspondiente automaticamente se agregue a la tabla que tengo abajo del inputo como se muestra en la imagen, como podria lograr conseguir eso? suponiendo que es el codigo de barras del producto el que se tendria que mandar a llamar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ajax seria la mejor solucion con el evento keyup

Comment: @WilsonicX, se me ocurre que en el método keyup, tal vez en el método input se envie ese dato mediante ajax, después al retornar la respuesta destruyas y vuelvas a crear la tabla.

Comment: @cignius pero eso no me borraria lo que ya tengo en la tabla?

Comment: ya que necesito ingresar varios productos, y lo ideal seria que regrese el focus al input text cada vez que se ingresa un producto

Comment: @precisamente cuando agregues un producto, lo que yo haría es tener una tabla temporal (Tal vez) donde guardes toda esa transacción, despues retornas la respuesta de los productos que agregaste. Te comento que al ser ajax no puedes actualizar "Automaticamente" la tabla, recuerda que todo lo que hagas debe ser en el momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esta es una de las formas mas cencilla que encuentro que podrias hacer lo que nececites

```
 $("#inputCode").keyup(function(){ 
var codigo=$("#codigo").val()//obtenermos el codigo escrito en el input

   if(codigo.length > 5){//si el valor de el codigo introducido es mayor a 5 ejecuta el ajax

    $.ajax({
                    url: 'traer_codigo.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { codigo: codigo},
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                     success: function (data) {                 
                         //execute call back.
                         //hacemos una nueva fila en la tabla eh introducimos los valores del call back en sus repestivos campos  
                         $('#mytablel').append(`
                            <tr>
                            <td>data["codigo"]</td>
                            <td>data["nombre"]</td>
                            <td>data["marca"]</td>
                            <td>data["precio"]</td>
                            <td>data["cantidad"]</td>
                            <td>data["importe"]</td>
                          </tr>`);

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status) {

                    },
                });
          });
}
```

**traer_codigo.php**

```
<?php
  $codigo=$_POST["codigo"];//recivimos desde ajax el valor del input
//en esta consulta estoy asumiendo que tu coneccion a la base de datos se llama conn
 $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM codigos WHERE codigo='$codigo'");

 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

//mandamos la informacion obtenidad de la consulta en un array multidimencional
 echo json_encode(array
                 ("codigo"=>$row["codigo"]
                 ,"nombre"=>$row["nombre"]
                 ,"marca"=>$row["marca"]
                 ,"precio"=>$row["precio"]
                 ,"cantidad"=>$row["cantidad"]
                 ,"importe"=>$row["importe"]
               ,))

?>
```

espero que te sirva saludos